# Package skype i386 problem with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: updates

If I do sudo apt-get update, it will show me:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package skype:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
sudo apt-get update gives me:

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the targeted solution to your question, but still, if you are willing to install skype, another workaround is to download its .deb file directly from skype's website:

http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/

Make sure to choose your distribution as Ubuntu 12.04 (Multiarch), download the deb file and open it with Ubuntu Software Center. Double clicking the download file will do just fine. That will get you skype installed.

Regarding duplicate entries in your update list, try:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-i386_Packages
```

in your terminal. Run `sudo apt-get update`
after that and see what happens next.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Software Sources or (run `software-properties-gtk`)
2. Other Software tab
3. Check for duplicated entry for `Canonical Partner`, Remove duplicate.
4. Then run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```